# Why does my png image jitter when loaded in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, png

I'm using Firefox 22.0 on Windows 7. When I load a scaled png image, the image **jitters/shakes** a little about a second after it is loaded. What's going on?

```
<a href="bozo">
    <img style="height:45px;" src="http://images.cdn.rackspace.com/header/logo-rackspace.png">
</a>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/getvictor/XAh2d/96/). I can reproduce the behavior by clicking Run.

I do not see this behavior on Chrome or IE.

Comment: I noticed the movement, but is so little, that only paying attention carefully in the moment it loads makes it noticeable.... I wouldnt spend much time for it. It must be the rendering engine, you could fill a bug in the mozilla tracker and maybe an expert will answer you.

Comment: I don't see any jitter on FF22 on Win7.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce, but it jitters because you set the size (and the wrong) by using CSS.

The image is 46 pixels in height and is first loaded as this, then the CSS is applied to it at 45 pixels which shrinks it by 1 pixel, hence the jitter. This little difference will show on the screen in a glimpse as it also affect the width, perhaps enough visible on some systems to make it appear to jitter.

If you set the image size to 46 pixels it should go away, or by setting the size as attributes:

```
<img height="46" ...
```